Is integral regular ring a UFD?
Let $A$ be a commutative ring such that it is regular and integral. It is known to all that for any prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ of $A$, $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is a UFD. My question is, whether $A$ itself is a UFD? In other word, whether Pic($A$) is trivial?

No, any Dedekind domain that isn't a UFD works as a counterexample. Typical examples include the affine coordinate ring of an elliptic curve or the ring of integers of a number field with class number $h > 1$.
